# Get gradient with respect to input for each sample - pytorch

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I have a question regarding the calculation of gradients w.r.t input using pytorch. In the forward pass of my network, I want to calculate the gradients of my network with respect to one input column (feature). However, I need this individually for each sample.

Right now I'm using out.sum() in the autograd function, however if I understand this right, this does not give me what I want.

Is there an efficient way to get the gradient in the forward pass of my network for each sample individually?

Best,

Gesetzt

```
class ComplexNet(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
            super(ComplexNet_GE, self).__init__()
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
            self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
            self.leaky_relu = nn.LeakyReLU()
            self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size)
            self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size)
            self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size)
            
    
        def forward(self, x):
            # Set input gradient to true
            x.requires_grad_(True)
    
            # Forward pass
            out = self.fc1(x)
            out = self.bn1(out)
            out = self.leaky_relu(out)
            out = self.fc2(out)
            out = self.bn2(out)
            out = self.leaky_relu(out)
            out = self.fc3(out)
            out = self.bn3(out)
            out = self.leaky_relu(out)
            out = self.fc4(out)
    
            # Compute the gradient with respect to all inputs
            grad_out_all = torch.autograd.grad(out.sum(), x, create_graph=True)[0]
    
            # Select the gradient of column 2
            grad_out = grad_out_all[:, 1].unsqueeze(1)        
    
            # Calculate gradients
            grad_1 = grad_out
            grad_2 = -grad_out
    
            # Concatenate these two into the final output
            final_out = torch.cat([grad_1, grad_2], dim=1)
    
            return final_out
```